# MS SQL JDBC error on Execution exception - Invalid object name [Play 2.x scala app]

Tags: sql, sql-server, scala, jdbc

I'm using Play framework 2.x with SQL driver: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

I'm trying to run a simple query:

```
SELECT [org].[name] FROM [ref].[organisations_bak] AS org
```

but I get the following error:

```
play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[SQLServerException: Invalid object name 'ref.organisations_bak'.]]
at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:293) ~[play_2.10-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:399) [play_2.10-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$12$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:165) [play_2.10-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$12$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:162) [play_2.10-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33) [scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
at scala.util.Failure$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Try.scala:185) [scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name 'ref.organisations_bak'.
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.2206.100.jar:na]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1515) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.2206.100.jar:na]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.doExecuteStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:792) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.2206.100.jar:na]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement$StmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerStatement.java:689) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.2206.100.jar:na]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.2206.100.jar:na]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.2206.100.jar:na]
```

I need to use the schema reference in my queries but I cant even get a simple query like this to work on my play app, simple queries without schema references work fine

```
SELECT name FROM organisations_bak
```

My Scala code looks like this:

```
import java.sql.ResultSet
import play.api.db.DB
DB.withConnection {
    conn =>
        val res = conn.createStatement.execute("SELECT [org].[name] FROM [ref].[organisations_bak] AS org")
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case the issue was different user permissions. The server I used for development has been setup in some weird way that my user didn't have the permission to access the [ref] schema.
Just as a test I switched over to an AWS RDS SQL Server instance with the default DBA (owner) user settings and everything worked.

This means that the library and the code works it's my server that's at fault, but that's another issue.

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
SELECT [org].[name] FROM [ref].[dbo].[organisations_bak] AS org
```